# On hovering a scatter plot in bokeh should display a image to the right of the graph

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to plot a scatter plot using bokeh, by importing dataset. Each point in the scatter plot resembles an image. On hovering it displays the image feature values.How can i display image with reference to its corresponding point at the right of plot or how can i clink on the point which displays an image link, on click of the link should display an image.

I have tried including path of image, but there are many images so, including path for all the images is quiet difficult.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure,show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,CDSView,GroupFilter
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure,output_file,show
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool

output_file('ColumnDataSource_example.html')
df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
sample=df.sample(100)
source=ColumnDataSource(sample)

Simple=CDSView(source=source,filters= 
[GroupFilters(Column_name='Complexity',group='Simple')])
Medium=CDSView(source=source,filters= 
[GroupFilters(Column_name='Complexity',group='Medium')])
Complex=CDSView(source=source,filters= 
[GroupFilters(Column_name='Complexity',group='Complex')])

p=figure()

p.circle(x='score',y='objects',source=source,view=Simple,
     size=10,color='green',alpha=0.6,legend='Simple')

p.square(x='score',y='objects',source=source,view=Medium,
     size=10,color='green',alpha=0.6,legend='Medium')

p.triangle(x='score',y='objects',source=source,view=Complex,
       size=10,color='green',alpha=0.6,legend='Complex')

p.title.text='Visualization'
p.xaxis.axis_label='Complexity'
p.yaxis.axis_label='No of objects'

hover=HoverTool()
hover.tooltips=[
('No of objects','@objects')
('Complexity','@score')
('Comments','@Comment')
]
p.add_tools(hover)
p.legend.location="top_left"
show(p)
```

Expected output should display image at the right of the scatter plot

Comment: Where are these images located?  Are they PNGs or GIFs, available at accessible URLs?

Comment: Images are in PNG, they are located in static folder of pycharm project.

Comment: There's not really going to be a good way. Bokeh plots are actually JavaScript programs that render to an HTML canvas. That means the images need to be accessible to the browser, which really means they need to be served by a web server.

Comment: @bigreddot is correct about serving up the files via a server but you could easily use a local server. Then just follow the example here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip